# Is the powers of $base-2$ always exponential in the number of digits?

Tags: algorithms, formal-proofs

Ignoring the value of $n$, focus on the length of $n$.

Here I'm interested in the decimal representation of input and outputs.

**Example**

For $2^n$, $n=15$.

- The solution for $2$^$15$ is $32768$.
- The length of $n$ is two digits and the solution is $3$ digits longer.

Another example is $2$^$100$

- The solution is $1267650600228229401496703205376$.
- The length of this large number is $31$ digits. And $n$ is $28$ digits shorter.

When solving this problem the digits returned on-screen are exponentially larger compared to the length of $n$.

### Question

What examples can be given for how the digits expand exponentially over-time?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking why the number of digits in $2^n$ is approximately proportional to $n$?

Comment: @J.G. I'm asking what proofs do we have to support the reasoning that this function problem can only be solved in $2^n$ time

Comment: @J.G. The number of digits is not proportional to $n$; if $100$ has $3$ digits and the solution has 31 digits. $31$ > the three digits in $100$

Comment: So are you asking why the number of digits in $2^n$, while being approximately proportional to the value of $n$, is much larger than the number of digits in $n$? Oh, because $\log_{10}(2^n)=n\log_{10}2\gg\log_{10}n$.

Comment: Who said there was a problem that can only be solved in $2^n$ time, and exactly what problem were they talking about? They were almost certainly **not** talking about the problem of writing the decimal representation of $2^n$, because that problem can be done a lot faster. So I think there is some other thing that someone said would take $2^n$ time measured as a function of $n$, and you have not told us anything about that other thing.

Comment: @DavidK You mean the binary representation of the powers of 2? Well, it takes $n$ $0-bits$ and $+$ one $1-bit$ to represent the solution. The 0-bits are proportional to the value of $n$. How would you work around the larger cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help if you gave a name to the size of your input. If the size you are concerned with is the number of digits of $n$, not the value, then let $d$ be the number of digits of input. In that case, the number of digits of output when you take a decimal number of $d$ digits, raise $2$ to that power, and write the result as a decimal number, will be between $0.03\times10^d$ and $0.3\times10^d.$

For example, if the input is $9$, then $d = 1$, the output is $512,$ which is $3$ digits of output, and $3 = 0.3 \times 10^1 = 0.3 \times 10^d,$ at the high end of the range predicted by "between $0.03\times10^d$ and $0.3\times10^d.$"

On the other hand, with an input of $100,$ you have $d = 3,$ and the output (as you found) has $31$ digits.
In this case $31 = 0.031 \times 10^3 = 0.031 \times 10^d,$ so it's near the low end of the range.

For $d= 10,$ the smallest result is when the input is 
$1{,}000{,}000{,}000$, in which case the output,
$2^{1{,}000{,}000{,}000}$ in decimal representation, has 
$301{,}029{,}995 > 0.03 \times 10^{10} = 0.03 \times 10^d$ digits.
Just to store the output on a computer (never mind displaying or printing it)
requires nearly $300$ MB of storage.

Now let's try an example with $d = 20.$ The number $20$ isn't what most people would consider a huge number.
But the smallest $20$-digit decimal number is
$10{,}000{,}000{,}000{,}000{,}000{,}000.$
And if you wanted to write the answer to the decimal representation of
$2^{10{,}000{,}000{,}000{,}000{,}000{,}000},$
you would need to write a decimal number with
$3{,}010{,}299{,}956{,}639{,}811{,}952 > 0.03 \times 10^{20} = 0.03 \times 10^d$ digits.
Just to store the output, you would need about $30000$ $100$-TB storage drives.

If we increase the size of the input to $d = 25,$ you need to compute the decimal representation of $2^{1{,}000{,}000{,}000{,}000{,}000{,}000{,}000{,}000}$ or something larger, with at least
$301{,}029{,}995{,}663{,}981{,}195{,}213{,}738
 > 0.03 \times 10^{25} = 0.03 \times 10^d$ digits, and now you need
$300$ million of those $100$-TB storage drives just to store the answer.

So if your algorithm is supposed to write the decimal representation of $2^n$ where $n$ is a decimal number of $d$ digits, the size of the output is proportional to $10^d$ and it becomes quite impractical just to store the output, let alone compute it, for values of $d$ that are only about $20$ or so.

---

In summary, if you measure the "size of input" by the number of bits, for example if we expect the input to be a random string of $d$ base-ten digits, any exponentiation algorithm is going to blow up as soon as the input gets much longer than a dozen digits, possibly sooner.

On the other hand, there aren't a lot of practical exponentiation problems where we're interested in answers for powers much above $1000$ ($d = 4$).
I would question whether it makes sense to measure the time complexity of an exponentiation algorithm using the same criterion (length of input in bits) as we do for a sorting algorithm.
It seems to me the complexity of exponentiation as a function of the number of bits of input is really interesting only to a handful of theoretical computer scientists, unlike the complexity of a typical sorting algorithm, which has many very practical consequences.

Answer (score 2):

The number of digits in the decimal expansion of $2^n$ will be about $\log_{10} (2^n) = n \log 2/ \log 10 \sim 0.3 n$.

Comment: And in turns $n$ is exponential in the number of its digits, giving the result that they expect.

Comment: @flan Basically, it takes $2^n$ space in order to display those digits on the computer screen? To solidify the reasoning even more. Exponential space always requires exponential time!

Comment: @TravisWells The space needed to display $2^n$ is proportional to $n$. It's only large if $n$ is itself large; it's not enough for $2^n$ to be large.

Comment: @J.G.  Yes, it is proportional to n. Algorithms' true complexity goes by length. Otherwise, we would be factoring large RSA numbers efficiently.

Comment: @TravisWells Factorization is a very different issue.

Comment: @J.G. Yes, they are different. But If I wanted to find the power of $base-2$ where $n$ is 1-million and I wanted to factor $1-million$ the number of steps in both naive methods would be exactly equal to 1-million.  1-million repeated multiplications of $2^n$ and 1-million steps in factoring. Both would be $2^n$ time.

Comment: @TravisWells I think you just asked the wrong question to begin with, and need to ask another one that talks about the real computational complexity issue that concerned you and start again. Also, perhaps you're not familiar with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).